# Update each 5-th td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need update each 5-th td. I write such jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var td = $('tbody td:nth-child(5)');
    var img = '/img/'+td.html().trim().toString();
    $.each(td, function(index, value){
        value.html('<img  src="' + img +'">');
    });
})
```

But it say me `Uncaught TypeError: value.html is not a function`. How i can fixed it?

Comment: The simplest way would be to give a class to the fifth td and target that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, `value` is a dom element reference not a jQuery object.

Also since you want to update the html content of each of the `td`, you will have to iterate and set the html as below else `img_link` will have only the value of the first `td` in the `td` set

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var td = $('tbody td:nth-child(5n)');

    td.html(function(i,html){
        return '<img height="120px" width="100px" src="' + html.trim() + '">'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `nth-child(5n)` to select each 5th element.

```
var td = $('tbody td:nth-child(5n)');
//                              ^ ------------ you missed n here
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tbody td:nth-child(5n)').each(function () {

        var img_link = '/img/category_img/' + $(this).html().trim();
        $(this).html('<img height="120px" width="100px" src="' + img_link + '">');
    });
});
```

Comment: `value` is a dom element reference, isn't it?

Comment: also `img_link` will have the contents from the first element from `td` set.... I think OP want to retain the content of each `td`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks +1. Looking at the code in question, it looks like OP don't want to retain content, he want to replace it by image

Comment: I think the image source comes from the content of each `td`!

Comment: else there is no need to loop... just `$('tbody td:nth-child(5n)').html('<img height="120px" width="100px" src="' + img_link + '">');` should do

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks again! Really missed that

Answer (score 2):

Give this way:

```
td.each(function(index, value) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have not noticed but you are missing an n in your query.
It should be `nth-child(5n)`

Below is the corrected query

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var td = $('tbody td:nth-child(5n)');
    var img = '/img/'+td.html().trim().toString();
    $.each(td, function(index, value){
        value.html('<img  src="' + img +'">');
    });
})
```